# SqlDependency not working properly MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

Error:

> When using SqlDependency without providing an options value, SqlDependency.Start() must be called prior to execution of a command added to the SqlDependency instance.

```
   public void someting()
    {     
        connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) from users", connection))
            {
                SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StringConnexion"].ConnectionString, "someting");

            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);



                dependency.OnChange += new
                    OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);


                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var int32 = reader.GetInt32(0);
                        MessageBox.Show(int32.ToString());
                        UserCount = int32.ToString();

                    }
                }
            }
```

I searched about this error and it means what It says, that I should start the Dependency which I have... so what's wrong?

Comment: If you want help implementing this in MVVM pattern (as stated in the question title), the answer is move this logic out of you UI layer completely. This is a job for a a different layer. Check out `Repository Pattern`

Comment: I tried the same thing without MVVM and receiving the same error.

Comment: try adding SqlDependency.Start in Startup class of your app

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota What does that mean? StartupUri in my App.xaml is "MainWindow.xaml", I should put the start there? because I did that already.

Comment: It doesn't match the error message, but the reason could be you using an invalid query, according to [Special Considerations Using Query Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aewzkxxh(v=vs.90))

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple things that might help:

1. `SqlDependency.Start()` may only be called once per AppDomain. So, it should go as close to your entry point as possible. And it definitely should be at least moved above your `using() {}` statement. If you call it more than once, you're going to run into problems.

   > MDSN:
   >   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency
   >
   > Notice how the SqlDependency.Start(...) is in an Initialize() method all by it's onesie.
2. It returns a `bool` so you can check the return value for debugging:

> `var isStarted = SqlDependency.Start( ... )`

3. Try explicitly adding the `Service=<SERVICE_NAME>` to your connection string (Unconfirmed if this actually helps, but it seemed to work for one user.